# How can I record wav file with Bits per Sample 8 16 and samples Per Second 16,000 8,000 11,025 11,000 6,000 in android?

Tags: android, record, wav

How i can record an audio file in `wav` format with above mentioned criteria.? give me an example if any one working around this.

> Bits per Sample
>
> 8
>     16
>
> samples Per Second
>
> 16,000 8,000 11,025 11,000 6,000

Comment: What about: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/audio-capture.html and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17192256/recording-wav-with-android-audiorecorder ?